# No, not, and non

Tags: grammar, morphology

Is there a specific rule, or set of rules, that can be followed to know when to use each word? I have noticed that not is usually used with a verb, but I think that there sometimes are exceptions although I can't think of one now.

Comment: Do you mean "exceptions"? Please correct if yes.

Comment: *At the linguistics conference, there were **no / not / non-** native speakers of Esperanto.* They're all grammatically "valid", but they all mean different things - and pragmatically / idiomatically, only the ***no*** version is likely to be used.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

*Not* is a negative adverb; *no* is a negative quantifier; *non*- is a negative prefix.
Since negation is so important, thousands of idioms use each of these, among other negatives.
Consequently there are **lots** of exceptions to the general rules below.

- *Non*- is not a word, but a part of another word, usually a descriptive adjective:
  *non-lethal, non-professional, non-native, non-technical, non-playing*
  (The hyphen is optional.)
  Each of these mean "anything but ..." -- anything that doesn't
  kill you is non-lethal, anything that's not technical is non-technical, etc.
  This meaning contrasts with *un*- and *in*-, which refer to opposites instead of complements.
- *No* is half of the answer pair *Yes/No*, shading off into *Nah, Nuh-uh,* and *Uh-uh*.
  But it can also quantify and negate any noun phrase:
  *Some blade of grass ~ No blade of grass; One who saw it ~ No one who saw it.*
- *Not* is the general negator for verb phrases, including predicate adjectives and nouns.
  In a verb phrase, *not* occurs immediately after the first auxiliary verb.
  If there is no auxiliary verb in the verb phrase, *Do*-Support supplies a form of *do*.
  *Not* is contracted whenever possible, with auxiliaries or subjects (especially pronouns):
  *He's not interested ~ He isn't interested; She doesn't like it*, but not **She not likes it*.

Any of these negatives ([and many others](http://www.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/CELS-Negation.pdf)) can negate a sentence, changing its truth value.
It's easy to switch between them, too; the sentences below all mean the same thing:

1. *They allowed no phone calls.*
2. *They didn't allow phone calls.*
3. *No one allowed phone calls.*
4. *Phone calls weren't allowed.*

Comment: I was wondering why you hadn't answered this. And then as if by magic... +

Comment: Would you say "We need something not interfering with the image" or  "We need something non interfering with the image"?

Comment: Neither one. I would say _We need something that doesn't interfere with the image,_ because _need_ doesn't take a gerund complement clause.

Comment: Re your comment, isn't "We need something not interfering with the image" grammatical even if considered as the elided variant of "We need something __which is_ not interfering with the image"? And what about the latter sentence('s grammaticality)?

Comment: So we can say non goes before an adjective, no goes beore a name, not goes before a verb.

Answer (score 7):

All of them have different usages and can quite clearly defined in that different contexts.

Some [example sentences](http://sentence.yourdictionary.com/no) for **no**:

> As for the drink, there was no point in bringing that up.
>
> Carmen had given Josh no encouragement.

Some examples sentences for **not**:

> I'm not too keen on that decision.
>
> That I am not prepared to say.

Some [example sentences](http://sentence.yourdictionary.com/not) for **non** as a prefix

> non-eligible
>
> non-human

After quite some time searching I couldn't find any rules in which those words obey to. As you can see in my linked sites though there are quite a few entries in which **not** is before a verb and little of any others. This is hard to draw a conclusion to make a hard and fast rule.

As you can see, it is quite defined in which each word is used. I can't think of any that could be used interchangeably at the moment. I'll accept suggestions to improve this.